# Jest not parsing es6: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

Tags: webpack, jestjs, babeljs

I am trying to setup Jest with my webpack project. When I run my tests, Jest complains it cannot read es6 code. Babel seems to not transform my test files.

I have tried various solutions I have found on the internet but I'm still stumped. Maybe somebody with more Babel/Webpack knowledge can look at my config and help me out.

relevant package.json script:

```
{
    "test": "jest --no-cache --config config/jest.config.js"
}
```

relevant package.json deps:

```
"@babel/core": "^7.2.2",
"@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
"@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
"babel-jest": "^24.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
"babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
"jest": "^24.0.0",
"webpack": "^4.29.0",
"webpack-cli": "^3.2.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.14"
```

config/webpack.config.js:

```
entry: './src/index.js',
mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
devtool: isProduction ? 'none' : 'inline-source-map',
bail: true,
devServer: {
  contentBase: 'build',
  compress: true,
  port: 3000,
},
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
  filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
},
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          cacheDirectory: true,
          presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            '@babel/preset-react',
            '@babel/preset-flow',
          ],
          plugins: [
            'babel-plugin-styled-components',
            '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  ],
},
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'src/index.html',
  }),
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': JSON.stringify(process.env),
  }),
],
```

config/jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  rootDir: '../',
  setupFiles: ['./config/jest.setup.js'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.js?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
```

config/jest.setup.js

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

jest error:
● Test suite failed to run

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
```

...

```
Details:

/<...projectpath>/config/jest.setup.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

I want some a working test runner! Im guessing my transform: babel-jest is doing nothing in my jest.config.js...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to do two things:

1. **Create a Babel config file** (`babel.config.js`):

   This is necessary because `babel-jest` relies on a traditional Babel config file, not webpack. Since version 7 Babel has supported JS configs as `babel.config.js`.

   When using a JS Babel config (as opposed to a `.babelrc`, for example) Jest also compiles modules in `node_modules`. AFAIK by convention this must be in the root of your project, alongside the jest configuration file.

   Here is a config based on the Babel options in your `webpack.config.js` file:

   ```js
   // babel.config.js
   module.exports = {
     presets: [
       '@babel/preset-env',
       '@babel/preset-react',
       '@babel/preset-flow',
     ],
     plugins: [
       'babel-plugin-styled-components',
       '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
     ]
   }
   ```
2. **Install the `babel-core` bridge version:**

   ```sh
   npm install babel-core@7.0.0-bridge.0 --save-dev
   ```

   From [github.com/babel/babel-bridge](https://github.com/babel/babel-bridge):

   > This repo holds what we're calling a "bridge" package that is meant to ease the transition for libraries that use "babel-core" as a peer dependency for Babel 6.
   >
   > The issue with Babel 7's transition to scopes is that if a package depends on Babel 6, they may want to add support for Babel 7 alongside. Because Babel 7 will be released as @babel/core instead of babel-core, maintainers have no way to do that transition without making a breaking change. e.g.

Comment: it works! can you please explain how and why?? also, this only works if my babel.config.js file is in the root directory and breaks when i put it in my config folder along with the webpack.config.js. this is also puzzling...

Comment: @NicholasMueller I updated the answer with some explanation.

Comment: @sdgluck I'm having the same problem with a project created with `create-react-app`. Because the configuration is hidden, I have no clue how the transpilation is being done. All I know is that `import` statements in node_modules don't get transpiled (and thus throws an error in jest). The above solution didn't help. Any ideas?

Comment: @sookie I believe in this instance you would need to [eject](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#npm-run-eject) from `create-react-app` and then follow the steps in this answer. If that doesn't work I recommend opening a new question.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar situation where I wanted to test a React component `.js` file with jest, but it was failing because the component imported a `.css` stylesheet. I was using Babel with Webpack.

As per the accepted answer @sdgluck, I had to add a `babel.config.js`:

**1.**

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
};
```

**2.** I also installed `babel-jest` as a dev-dependency

**3.** Then I read through the [jest webpack guide](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack)

**4.** Which led me to adding a "jest" property to my `package.json` which mocks files and stylesheets:

```
"jest": {
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  }
```

**5.** Then I had to create the mocked files at the specified paths (you can use any path you want, those are just from their docs):

```
// __mocks__/styleMock.js

module.exports = {};
```

```
// __mocks__/fileMock.js

module.exports = 'test-file-stub';
```

Then it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

I have some useful information that can be used as a reference for those who see this problem later.

By default, **transformIgnorePatterns** in jest config was [["/node_modules/", "\.pnp\.[^\/]+$"]](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transformignorepatterns-arraystring)

If some guys issue was caused by **some code in node_modules** and do not overwrite this value, babel-jest still not working.

Maybe the correct value like this **"/node_modules/(?!(your-third-part-es-module-code|others-es-lib))"**