# Import error when running Jest tests that use the PouchDB Asyncstorage adapter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm getting this error when running tests in Jest. I've tried mocking pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage and the polyfill both in the module, automock, and globally.

Without modifying pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage library, how can I squash this issue?

Update: Based on my research, it seems that this library hasn't been fully updated to an ES6 module and babel might be able transform it.

[pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage source code](https://github.com/stockulus/pouchdb-react-native/blob/master/packages/pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage/src/index.js)

```js
  ● Test suite failed to run

node_modules/pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage/src/index.js:3
    import './polyfill'
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected string


    > 1 | import AsyncStorage from 'pouchdb-adapter-asyncstorage'
      2 | import React from 'react'
```

Comment: You need to ask the author of that weird adapter library.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54461150/jest-not-parsing-es6-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import